# Google Play Store Private Channel and own domain

Tags: google-play

I just register and paid $25 USD to be able to upload an app in the Google Play Store. I used my personal email address, something like sonyaATmydomain.com. The app that I am uploading is for a different domain, e.g. hello.com. I uploaded the app and started to configure all the settings. The problem is that I did not realize that to make the app private (Private Channel) my developers email account must be the same domain as the app, e.g. sonyaAThello.com. So I added a new user with administrator permissions to the app, this new user using the correct domain, e.g. sonyaAThello.com. I logged with this new user account and I cannot see the Private Channel section. Then I logged with my personal email address user and also I couldn't see the option. Then I discovered that to see that section my setup account (the one that paid $25 USD) must be the app domain. But that is not possible. So I tried to transfer the app from my personal account to the new user domain account, BUT at this stage I doubt that is going to work. For what I have read, it seems to enable the private channel, I must have a Goggle Apps account and that is not free. Does anyone know if it is possible to setup the private channel for the play store without having to pay a Google Apps subscription and if yes what's the correct process? Unfortunately I already paid $25 USD but I can't manage to get the private channel :(, thanks a lot

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google policies. Stack Overflow is not Google product support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off the [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2623322), it seems there is no getting around having a Google Apps for Work, Education, or Government account.

This work around may not work for you, but what you can do is [publish to aplha/beta testers](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en). This will allow you to grant access to whatever users or groups of your choosing. You do not need a production APK for aplha/beta testing, but I'm not sure if you'll be able to get other production information (analytics, ratings, etc).